# What happens when awaiting on already-completed task?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

When I construct an instance of a class that I have, I would like to trigger a Token renewal function (`async` method) and let it run in the background (I keep a reference to the returned `Task`).

Later on, when a user triggers a request, I would like to await on that `Task`.

Lets assume that the `Task` completes after 1 second, and that the user triggers a request after 2 seconds (which means, the `Task` is completed).

The method that handles the user's request `await`s that `Task`, would it get the value immediately? after all, the `Task` is completed and holds the value.

Comment: Yes, it would immediately return the result.

Comment: @MatthewWatson why didn't you write it as an answer? I would have accepted your answer.

Comment: It wasn't really long enough or detailed enough to write as an answer, I thought.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> The method that handles the user's request awaits that Task, would it get the value immediately?

Yes. You can think of it as being lazy, if you `await` a task that is already completed it returns immediately. You could await it several times on different threads and it would only return once it has the result (or is faulted).

[`Task.CompletedTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask(v=vs.110).aspx) was added as a nicety for this very reason. You could `await` this and it would immediately return a successful task as it has already been completed.

Answer (score 6):

Though the OP didn't mention `ValueTask`, I'm adding this answer to include `ValueTask` since it has been added after this question was originally asked.

- With regard to `Task` and `Task<T>`, as others have noted, you can
  await a `Task` (or completed `Task`) multiple times.  If the task has
  run to completion, it returns immediately.
- However, if you are using a `ValueTask` or `ValueTask<T>`, you cannot await it more
  than once.  `ValueTask` and `ValueTask<T>` were introduced in .NET
  Core 2.0 and are used to avoid/minimize memory allocations for performance-sensitive areas.

As taken from Stephen Toub on the Dotnet Blog:

> However, because ValueTask and ValueTask may wrap reusable
>   objects, there are actually significant constraints on their
>   consumption when compared with Task and Task, should someone
>   veer off the desired path of just awaiting them. In general, the
>   following operations should never be performed on a ValueTask /
>   ValueTask:
>
> - **Awaiting a ValueTask / ValueTask multiple times**. The
>     underlying object may have been recycled already and be in use by
>     another operation. In contrast, a Task / Task will never
>     transition from a complete to incomplete state, so you can await it as
>     many times as you need to, and will always get the same answer every
>     time.
> - **Awaiting a ValueTask / ValueTask concurrently**. The
>     underlying object expects to work with only a single callback from a
>     single consumer at a time, and attempting to await it concurrently
>     could easily introduce race conditions and subtle program errors. It’s
>     also just a more specific case of the above bad operation: “awaiting a
>     ValueTask / ValueTask multiple times.” In contrast, Task /
>     Task do support any number of concurrent awaits.
> - **Using
>     .GetAwaiter().GetResult() when the operation hasn’t yet completed**. The
>     IValueTaskSource / IValueTaskSource implementation need not
>     support blocking until the operation completes, and likely doesn’t, so
>     such an operation is inherently a race condition and is unlikely to
>     behave the way the caller intends. In contrast, Task / Task
>     do enable this, blocking the caller until the task completes.
>
> If you have a ValueTask or a ValueTask and you need to do one of
>   these things, you should use .AsTask() to get a Task / Task
>   and then operate on that resulting task object. After that point, you
>   should never interact with that ValueTask / ValueTask again.
>
> **The short rule is this: with a ValueTask or a ValueTask, you
>   should either await it directly (optionally with
>   .ConfigureAwait(false)) or call AsTask() on it directly, and then
>   never use it again**, e.g.

and from the MSDN documentation on `ValueTask` and `ValueTask<T>`:

> The following operations should never be performed on a
>   ValueTask instance:
>
> - Awaiting the instance multiple times.
> - Calling AsTask multiple times.
> - Using .Result or .GetAwaiter().GetResult() when the operation hasn't    yet completed, or using them multiple times.
> - Using more than one of these techniques to consume the instance.
>
> **If you do any of the above, the results are undefined.**

You can read more about `ValueTask` and `ValueTask<T>` [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1?view=netcore-3.1).

Answer (score 5):

You can create a completed task using Task.FromResult(value) and await it:

```
var result = await Task.FromResult(5);
Debug.Assert(result == 5);
```

This is useful for example if you have a method which can return cached data but needs to fetch it asynchronously the first time.

So, yes, you can await already completed tasks.

Comment: Note that, if you call `await` several time, it will return it every time and by reference if it's not a value. I'm unsure if it's 100% the same for actual task or not but I would assume so.

Answer (score 1):

You will have immédiat the result. Once the task is complete, its result property will contain the result and keep it.